# Type of a subSetoid

Tags: agda

Is there a way for a function to ask for two `Setoid`s where equality in the first `Setoid` implies equality in the latter? Of course this requires that both `Setoid`s share their `Carrier` and `Carrier` is not a parameter, but a record field instead. A naive attempt to request `Carrier` equality gets rejected by the type checker:

```
f : {S₁ S₂ : Setoid _ _} → Setoid.Carrier S₁ ≡ Setoid.Carrier S₂ →
    ({x y : Setoid.Carrier S₁} → Setoid._≈_ S₁ x y → Setoid._≈_ S₂ x y ) → ...
```

This does not work, because we do not pattern match on the equality proof, so the different `Carrier` types are not unified. I have not found a way to express this using `subst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. I'm using the following shortcuts:

```
A = Setoid.Carrier S₁
B = Setoid.Carrier S₂
```

You can either transport the elements `x` and `y` from `A` to `B`, or you can transport the relation `Setoid._≈_ S₂` from `B → B → Set _` to `A → A → Set _`.

Transporting elements can be done via `subst id`:

```
f : ∀ {c ℓ} {S₁ S₂ : Setoid c ℓ}
    (p : Setoid.Carrier S₁ ≡ Setoid.Carrier S₂) →
    (∀ {x y} → Setoid._≈_ S₁ x y →
               Setoid._≈_ S₂ (subst id p x) (subst id p y)) →
    ?
```

Notice that `subst id : A ≡ B → A → B` (roughly).

Transporting the whole relation can then be done via `subst (λ x → x → x → Set _)`. We start with `B → B → Set _`, so we need a proof `B ≡ A` instead of `A ≡ B` - that's why we use `sym`:

```
g : ∀ {c ℓ} {S₁ S₂ : Setoid c ℓ}
    (p : Setoid.Carrier S₁ ≡ Setoid.Carrier S₂) →
    (∀ {x y} → Setoid._≈_ S₁ x y →
               subst (λ x → x → x → Set _) (sym p) (Setoid._≈_ S₂) x y) →
    ?
```

---

It's hard to tell which one will be easier to work with. Another option is to work directly with `IsEquivalence`, this allows you to simply force the relations to be over the same domain:

```
h : ∀ {a ℓ} {A : Set a} {_≈₁_ _≈₂_ : Rel A ℓ}
    {E₁ : IsEquivalence _≈₁_} {E₂ : IsEquivalence _≈₂_} →
    (∀ {x y} → x ≈₁ y → x ≈₂ y) →
    ?
```